# JSON Array Sort on Php

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to order a json array by id in php but I have some errors, I have searched in forums but I cannot find the solution to my problem, my data structure, it is like this:

```
[
{"id": 2,"name": xx},
{"id": 20,"name": xx},
{"id": 10,"name": xx},
{"id": 5,"name": xx},
{"id": 1,"name": xx},
]
```

Comment: Please post your code and the full error message in order to get useful answers

Comment: Please go read [ask] and [mre].

Answer (score 1):

You can do that like this
first convert it to php array
then sort it and if you like you can encode it again to json

```
$jsonString = '[{"id":2,"name":"xx"},{"id":20,"name":"xx"},{"id":10,"name":"xx"},{"id":5,"name":"xx"},{"id":1,"name":"xx"}]';

//first lets convert it to php array
$jsonArray = json_decode($jsonString, true);


//the sorting function
function sortByID($a, $b) {
    return $a['id'] > $b['id'];
}

usort($jsonArray , 'sortByID'); //$jsonArray is now sorted by ID (ascending)

var_dump($jsonArray);

//if you like you can encode it to json again
$jsonEncode = json_encode($jsonArray);

var_dump($jsonEncode);
```

if you would like to sort by something else you just need to change the array index in `sortByID` function

that's it